# Gambler's ruin, fun problem

Tags: mathematical-statistics

*This is mostly for fun and because I haven't found it on here. Hopefully nobody looks up the answer online for it ruins the challenge. Best answer will be chosen on who can solve this in their own way. If you look up the answer at least give it your own flavor.*

### Gambler's Ruin

A gambler has a certain amount of money $M$ and is playing a game of chance with some win probability less than 1. Every time he wins, he raises his stake to a certain fraction, $1/N$, of his bankroll, where $N$ is a positive number. The gambler doesn't reduce his stake when he loses

Every time he wins, he'll raise his stake to  $M/N$, or his bankroll divided by $N$. When $M= 1000$ and $N=4$, for example, he'll gamble $250 M$ each time going forward. Should he win, he'll raise it again. Should he lose, he'll keep his stake at $250 M$.

If he keeps at it, what are his expected winnings?

Comment: What happens if, after losing a gamble & refusing to reduce his bet, he has $d\ <\ ^M\!\!/_N$ left over? Does he stop betting & that is his final winnings?

Comment: What do you think happens?

Comment: The notation used here gets in the way of a precise description of the problem. For example, what is $B$ and how does it relate to $M$? Being clear about the stopping condition is (also) an integral part of describing the process.

Comment: How much money does it take before the gambler leaves the table? As the problem is currently stated, I think stochastic differential equations is required, though analytically solving an eigenvector of an unbounded left stochastic matrix with an absorbing state might be possible.

Comment: @cardinal $B$ was a typo. I meant $M$. It is corrected above.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie. So the last two $M$'s are also extraneous, then? I think a concrete response to @gung's question would be a helpful addition. Cheers.

Comment: How can he/she gamble 250x the bank roll?

Comment: @cardinal yes he/she loses.

Comment: 4 losses in a row will reduce his stake to 0. Expected earnings as a function of turn t, winning probability p and N might be interesting, though.

Comment: This sound like a Martingale variation, and the result depend on the *win probability*, which is unspecified, and which would ensure ruin after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this is a trick question.

If he keeps at it, and the probability is less than 1, his winnings are zero. He will eventually lose it all.

Comment: Although this answer may be correct, it needs justification. The certainty of an eventual loss does not imply the expected winnings are zero! The standard example of this occurs when a gambler has even odds on a fair coin flip and just lets her winnings ride: although she is certain to lose (in the limit as the number of plays increases), the limiting expected value of this strategy is one-half her initial stake.

Comment: After reading the comment from whuber, I think this question would be much clearer with a definition of winnings.

Comment: This kind of spoils it but you can't win at all.